# trigger postgis and dump qgis 2.8.2

Tags: qgis, postgis, trigger

I created a trigger that checks if geometry is valid on insert and update.

```
        create or replace function check_geom() returns trigger as
$$
begin
--insert a polygon
IF st_isvalid(new.geom) = 'f'
THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'erreur de topologie' ;
END IF ;
RETURN NULL ;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_check_geom ON public.uniteobservation ;
CREATE TRIGGER trg_check_geom AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE on public.uniteobservation
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_geom();
```

I have an error message when I create a feature with a wrong geometry (self intersection,...). I can correct and validate it.
But I can't update a second times : QGIS mini dump each time I select a vertex again.
Any idea ?

Comment: have you tried to return new.* on success ?

Comment: you mean if st_isvalid(new.geom) = 't' ?

Comment: ... maybe. I mean : 
IF st_isvalid(new.geom) = 'f'
THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'erreur de topologie' ;
ELSE
 (INSERT data here and call return ) 
RETURN NEW
END IF ;

end;

Comment: I tried ELSE RETURN NEW ;END IF ;..Whatever I change mini dump always on update...even when erasing RETURN NULL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a trigger, you can add a constraint based on `st_isvalid()`, like:

```
ALTER TABLE public.uniteobservation
  ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_valid_geom CHECK (st_isvalid(geom));
```

Other useful constraints, that you might consider **to ensure the consistency of user editings**, especially when several users are using QGIS to edit data are:

```
ALTER TABLE public.uniteobservation
ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_type_polygon CHECK (geometrytype(geom) = 'POLYGON'::text OR geometrytype(geom) = 'MULTIPOLYGON'::text OR geom IS NULL);

ALTER TABLE public.uniteobservation
CONSTRAINT enforce_dims CHECK (st_ndims(geom) = 2);

ALTER TABLE public.uniteobservation
CONSTRAINT enforce_srid CHECK (st_srid(geom) = 3857);
```

Comment: Why not...good idea. Let's work on it.

Comment: I made my decision : I am keeping the constraint solution. It works and I can't debug my trigger.